# Is there a grunt plugin for submitting a pull request to github?

Tags: node.js, github, open-source, gruntjs

Seems like this would be a very useful tool to help people contribute to open source libraries. I'll take the answer off the air.

Comment: It is a requested feature here: https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-git/issues/24 and the testing issue that the author mentions has been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. use the github-api package:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/github-api

(from their docs)

Create Pull Request.

```
var pull = {
  title: message,
  body: "This pull request has been automatically generated by Prose.io.",
  base: "gh-pages",
  head: "michael" + ":" + "prose-patch",
};
repo.createPullRequest(pull, function(err, pullRequest) {});
```